# R Sum a Column Grouped By Other Columns With Rollups

Tags: r

I've already written the following, which will summarize a target column from the input dataset, and includes partial sums (or rollups or whatever the preferred vernacular may be) for each of the other columns present.

This works fine but has an undesirable nested `for` loop, which I would like to remove in favor of more "functional" approach. I already attempted this, but despite more than a little reading and practice, I remain in a state of *non-grokkery* when it comes to the various `apply` and/or `dplyr` functions.

It may well be that everything I'm doing is wrong; e.g. the setup to prep for the loops may be unnecessary if the final solution doesn't need it, etc... basically I just want the generate the expected ouput when given the provided input...

Anyway, here's the code:

```
# dummy data -- assume this is given 
#######################################################################
df1 <- c("AA","B","AA","B","AA","B","AA","B","AA","B","AA","B",
         "M","M","N","N","M","M","N","N","M","M","N","N",
         "X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z","Z",
         2,3,4,4,2,3,5,4,3,2,5,4)
dim(df1) <- c(12,4)
colnames(df1) <- c("f1","f2","f3","cnt")
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1,stringsAsFactors=F)
df1$cnt <- as.integer(df1$cnt)
#######################################################################
library(data.table)

# some hard-coded variables...
anyStr <- "(any)"       # this string cannot appear in df1
targetColName <- "cnt"  # name of the column being summed from df1
outputColName <- "sum"  # name of our output column

# grab names of only the columns we're going after... (just do everything but the target)
colsToSummarize = (colnames(df1)[!colnames(df1) %in% list(targetColName)])

# create a data table of just the unique values for each of those columns...
df2 <- lapply(colsToSummarize, function(x) { unique(df1[,x])})
df2 <- as.data.table(df2)

# add a dummy row that basically means "any value" ...
# this string cannot otherwise be present in the data...
df2 <- rbind(df2,as.data.table(t(rep(anyStr,length(df2)))))
colnames(df2) <- c(colsToSummarize)

# expand df2 to generate all possible settings found in df1...
df2 <- unique(expand.grid(df2))
rownames(df2)<-NULL

# do all the sums... there's probably a clever way to do this using "apply" functions...
df2[,eval(outputColName)] <- 0
for (i2 in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  for (i1 in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    isMatch = T
    for (j in colsToSummarize) {
      if ((df2[i2,eval(j)]!=anyStr) & (df1[i1,eval(j)]!=df2[i2,eval(j)])) {
        isMatch = F
        break
      }
    }
    if (isMatch) {
      df2[i2,eval(outputColName)] = df2[i2,eval(outputColName)] + df1[i1,eval(targetColName)]
    }
  }
}
```

So, the sample dummy data looks like:

```
> df1
   f1 f2 f3 cnt
1  AA  M  X   2
2   B  M  X   3
3  AA  N  X   4
4   B  N  X   4
5  AA  M  Y   2
6   B  M  Y   3
7  AA  N  Y   5
8   B  N  Y   4
9  AA  M  Z   3
10  B  M  Z   2
11 AA  N  Z   5
12  B  N  Z   4
```

... and the expected output:

```
> df2
      f1    f2    f3 sum
1     AA     M     X   2
2      B     M     X   3
3  (any)     M     X   5
4     AA     N     X   4
5      B     N     X   4
6  (any)     N     X   8
7     AA (any)     X   6
8      B (any)     X   7
9  (any) (any)     X  13
10    AA     M     Y   2
11     B     M     Y   3
12 (any)     M     Y   5
13    AA     N     Y   5
14     B     N     Y   4
15 (any)     N     Y   9
16    AA (any)     Y   7
17     B (any)     Y   7
18 (any) (any)     Y  14
19    AA     M     Z   3
20     B     M     Z   2
21 (any)     M     Z   5
22    AA     N     Z   5
23     B     N     Z   4
24 (any)     N     Z   9
25    AA (any)     Z   8
26     B (any)     Z   6
27 (any) (any)     Z  14
28    AA     M (any)   7
29     B     M (any)   8
30 (any)     M (any)  15
31    AA     N (any)  14
32     B     N (any)  12
33 (any)     N (any)  26
34    AA (any) (any)  21
35     B (any) (any)  20
36 (any) (any) (any)  41
```

Naturally, I'm OK with output that is essentially the same; (e.g. NA or blanks or whatever instead of "(any)", order of rows/columns is not important, etc...)

Aside: this is not identical to a SQL `group by with rollup` since this provides all permutations rather than a subset based on the order of variables in  your `group by` clause... if someone reading this wants that subset, they would simply need to remove rows that contain unexpected "(any)" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use addmargins() in combination with ftable() for this.
First the table, where you sum up cnt for the groups:

```
    table1 <- xtabs(cnt ~f1 + f2 + f3, data= df1)
> table1
, , f3 = X

    f2
f1   M N
  AA 2 4
  B  3 4

, , f3 = Y

    f2
f1   M N
  AA 2 5
  B  3 4

, , f3 = Z

    f2
f1   M N
  AA 3 5
  B  2 4
```

Then use addmargins() to calculate partial sums

```
tablle2 <- addmargins(table1)
> tablle2
, , f3 = X

     f2
f1     M  N Sum
  AA   2  4   6
  B    3  4   7
  Sum  5  8  13

, , f3 = Y

     f2
f1     M  N Sum
  AA   2  5   7
  B    3  4   7
  Sum  5  9  14

, , f3 = Z

     f2
f1     M  N Sum
  AA   3  5   8
  B    2  4   6
  Sum  5  9  14

, , f3 = Sum

     f2
f1     M  N Sum
  AA   7 14  21
  B    8 12  20
  Sum 15 26  41
```

finally ftable() to bring it in a nice form:

```
table3 <- ftable(tablle2)
> table3
        f3  X  Y  Z Sum
f1  f2                 
AA  M       2  2  3   7
    N       4  5  5  14
    Sum     6  7  8  21
B   M       3  3  2   8
    N       4  4  4  12
    Sum     7  7  6  20
Sum M       5  5  5  15
    N       8  9  9  26
    Sum    13 14 14  41
```

As last use as.data.frame to bring is in the form mentioned in the question:

```
 table4 <- as.data.frame(table3)
   > table4
        f1  f2  f3 Freq
    1   AA   M   X    2
    2    B   M   X    3
    3  Sum   M   X    5
    4   AA   N   X    4
    5    B   N   X    4
    6  Sum   N   X    8
    7   AA Sum   X    6
    8    B Sum   X    7
    9  Sum Sum   X   13
    10  AA   M   Y    2
    11   B   M   Y    3
    12 Sum   M   Y    5
    13  AA   N   Y    5
    14   B   N   Y    4
    15 Sum   N   Y    9
    16  AA Sum   Y    7
    17   B Sum   Y    7
    18 Sum Sum   Y   14
    19  AA   M   Z    3
    20   B   M   Z    2
    21 Sum   M   Z    5
    22  AA   N   Z    5
    23   B   N   Z    4
    24 Sum   N   Z    9
    25  AA Sum   Z    8
    26   B Sum   Z    6
    27 Sum Sum   Z   14
    28  AA   M Sum    7
    29   B   M Sum    8
    30 Sum   M Sum   15
    31  AA   N Sum   14
    32   B   N Sum   12
    33 Sum   N Sum   26
    34  AA Sum Sum   21
    35   B Sum Sum   20
    36 Sum Sum Sum   41
```

Comment: It's not quite the output format I'm after, which is why I didn't spend much time with `addmargins`. I'm no expert though; perhaps for others this format would be preferred.  Thanks for the insight... actually, I wonder if there's a quick way to transition from what you've generated to my output format...

Comment: I will update with a other suggestion, it is to long, to post in a comment

Comment: great that I could help :-)
I will just edit the answer, deleting the questions.